# Invalid Syntax, function won't accept return instead throws invalid syntax

Tags: python, syntax, return

Code below throws the error invalid syntax at the `return Total` line. I think there's an issue with my while loop but I don't see it. I'm trying to compute factorials with the code below. So the `print factorial(4)` section would compute 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 and return `24` to the console.

```
def factorial(x):
    Total = int(x)
    fact = int(x) - 1
    while fact >= 1:
        Total *= fact
        fact -= 1\
    return Total

print factorial(4)
```

I also tried the code below so it would `print Total` vs `Return Total`.

```
def factorial(x):
    Total = int(x)
    fact = int(x) - 1
    while fact >= 1:
        Total *= fact
        fact -= 1\
    print Total

print factorial(4)
```

When I use 1 as an input it returns:

Your function crashed on 1 as input because your function throws a "unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'" error.

Comment: Why did you get rid of the ```\``` character in your question?

Comment: Please post more code that's located above what you've shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**:

Since you're modified your question, the code you've posted is correct. The issue exists elsewhere. It's just parsing and throwing the error where you're seeing it.

**Original**:
It's in the line `fact -= 1\`. The `\` tells it that the next line is actually part of the current line. so it's reading this:

```
  fact -= 1 print Total
```

instead of

```
  fact -= 1
  print Total
```

Answer (score 2):

Delete the `\` at the end of this line `fact -= 1\`

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `\` on this line:

```
fact -= 1\
```

The `\` indicates a line continuation, which would throw a syntax error

A good rule to follow:  Always check the preceding line when you get a confusing syntax error